# MacBook pro 15 inch 2019 screen flickers with purple horizontal lines when iPhone is near my MacBook screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, screen

When i bring my iPhone near my MacBook pro screen, the screen flickers with horizontal lines. I have tested the flickering with iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max. All the devices are up to date with the latest software. I noticed that the flickering is not happening when I keep the device at aeroplane mode.
Has anyone encountered this issue?

[image: flic]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the MacBook's hardware is very much more susceptible to RF interference than it ought to be. You should never see artefacts such as those. It might be that there is a build fault (e.g. accidental omission of some shielding component), or some other hardware fault that is causing the unusual sensitivity issues.

You should take the computer to an Apple authorised service centre where you can demonstrate the issue for assessment and repair options.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal. It happens on my macbook and another laptop as well, and I have seen it on other macbooks and a TV as well. On the macbook it looks just like your photo.

It only happens if the phone is leaning on the screen and has data activity - the simple solution is to not lean your phone on your screen.

This is the visual equivalent of the audible buzzing you might hear on speakers.